# HighCharts Pie chart, 50+ labels, not showing all of them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, charts, highcharts

I am creating a Donut Pie chart in which I have to show all countries of Asia some 50+. Now the problem is, it is not showing all of the dataLabels. Here is what I am getting:

[image]

Possible solution would be to decrease the line spacing/ distance between the labels. Or any other solution?

Comment: Access to image is not possible: *HTTP1.1 STATUS 403 Remote Access to this object forbidden*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the dataLabels [padding](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.pie.dataLabels.padding) option to 0:

```
series: [{
   name: 'Asia',
   data: data,
   innerSize: '40%',                
   showInLegend:true,
   dataLabels: {
       enabled: true,
       padding: 0
   }
}]
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Pm5yz/).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did a test with 35 data points/labels and that is true that some of labels are not shown. In my case the reason is dimension of chart. There is no enough space for all labels. All slices are shown but some labels are not.

Solution is to increase size of chart changing `height` property. For example:

```
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            defaultSeriesType: 'pie',
            borderWidth: 1,
            height: 650
        },
```

With different heights different number of labels are shown.